# Vue component maximum recursive updates exceeded with vite HMR

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite

When I changed something in a Vue nested component and saved it. The **Vite HMR** will constantly reload the component. And then it caused a warning of vue: **Maximum recursive updates exceeded...**

[**Try online Demo on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vy4uyb?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FChild1.vue).
Change something in Child1.vue and save. You can see 101 times same info and a warning in console.

**Or code blow with Vue3.x + Vite4.x/5.x:**

Child1.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emits = defineEmits(['list-change']);

emits('list-change', ['a', 'b', 'c']);

// change something and save
console.log('Child1.vue setup');
</script>
```

Child2.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  list: string[];
}>();
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <Child1 @list-change="handleListChange"></Child1>
  <Child2 :list="list"></Child2>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Child1 from './components/Child1.vue';
import Child2 from './components/Child2.vue';

const list = ref<string[]>([]);
const handleListChange = (newList: string[]) => {
  list.value = newList;
};

console.log('App.vue setup');
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: *This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself* - the warning tells you what you're doing wrong, if you read the WHOLE warning

Comment: @JaromandaX yes of course I read the warning but there's no such mutatings in the three components.

Comment: yeah, I see ... something odd about doing the `emit` in the `setup` though - if you wrap it in a setTimeout then the issue goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is you are calling `emits('list-change', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'o']);` directly on child load , what is happening here is that first app loads that registers function for list-change event then child1 loads and emits that event , now app will listen event and updates list and re-renders whole app cus child2 is using that list , that will again load child1 (cuz of re-render) and again event will be emmited , this loop goes on and on till stack is full.

to prevent this keep emits call in function and call that function in button click

##### Child1

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emits = defineEmits(['list-change']);
function test() {
  console.log('Updating List');
  emits('list-change', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'o']);
}

// change something and save
console.log('Child1.vue setup');
</script>
<template>
  <button @click="test">TEST 2</button>
</template>
```

or use `onMount`

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {onMount} from 'vue';
const emits = defineEmits(['list-change']);

onMount(() => {
emits('list-change', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'o']);
});


// change something and save
console.log('Child1.vue setup');
</script>
```

Comment: or just in a setTimeout

Comment: Yup @JaromandaX anything that takes emit outside of initialization flow , event timeout od 0s will also work :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I'm confused why "...re-renders whole app cus child2 is using that list...". And this problem will only be casued while developing 
 with vite, not in production after build. If the rerender is due to the prop bind in Child2.vue, the problem will exist in production. So I'm confused. And Is there any way to solve it if the emit just needs to be done in setup, such as something need to be inited locally when component create.

Comment: You need to understand vue lifecycle for this https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle#lifecycle-diagram

you can use onMounted hook to prevent this
```
<script setup>
import {onMounted} from 'vue';
onMounted(() => emits('list-update', [1,2,3,4]))
</script>
```

Comment: @DarshanPatel After long time trying to understand the process before mount, I almost get it~XD... I simply assume that changes of reactive data before mounting will make component rerender/reload and then trigger setup hook again and again... Thanks a lot for your advice and patience :)